# How to I open another app within an app in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, uwp

So I'm trying to open a maximum of two apps concurrently, the user, clicks a button listed on the navigation menu and then the app opens in the blank red area of the top level app, like so:

[image]

**Here is the xaml code for this page:**

```
    <Grid Background="#d80202">
        <NavigationView x:Name="Navigation">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem x:Name="Home" Icon="Home" Content="Home"/>
                <NavigationViewItem x:Name="Colours" Icon="Edit" Content="Colours"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Admin" Content="Security"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="World" Content="Translate"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
```

**Here is the code for the mainPage's .cs:**

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Debug.WriteLine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName);
        }

        private void Navigation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
        }

        private async void NavigateToColoursApp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            var options = new LauncherOptions();
            options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "e8731a5c-2685-436a-b3c7-983a3b74fb9a_bnk8fdhtvqpqp";
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("Colours.xaml"), options);
        }

        private void Navigation_Navigate(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                switch (item.Content)
                {
                    case "Home":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;

                    case "Colours":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Colours));
                        break;

                    case "Translate":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Translate));
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**And for an example of the navigation, here is the Colours page's .cs**

```
        public Colours()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Debug.WriteLine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

An app cannot be opened "inside" another app. An app is a process that runs in isolation from other processes/apps.

Besides, the type of the `Content` property of the `SplitView` control is `UIElement` which effectively means that you cannot set it to anything else than a `UIElement`. And since neither a `Window` or an app is a `UIElement`, you'll have to rethink your approach here.

Instead of trying to include an entire app into the `SplitView`, you should break out its contents into a control that you can display and use in any app.